# rasa syntax to predict sentence by sentence

Tags: rasa

I want to use [rasa](https://rasa.com/) like the normal model, where I can load the model, and predict the intents of each sentence individually, rather than calling some `rasa test` or `rasa test` [prebuilt apis](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/testing-your-assistant/).

Can someone please let me know how to do like this:

```
rasa_model.load("x.tgz")
rasa_model.predict("Predict for this sentence!!")
```

Comment: There are multiple models in rasa. Rasa core, NLU etc. which model do you want to test?

Comment: it is about rasa nlu.. to classify sentence one by one.. using model.predict syntax

Comment: Check the answer. I have added two ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**The optimal solution is to do with an [NLU server](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu-only/#running-an-nlu-server).**

1). Run rasa from your terminal/command prompt

```
rasa run --enable-api -m models/x.tar.gz
```

2). Send a request to your local server from another terminal/command prompt

```
curl localhost:5005/model/parse -d '{"text":"Predict for this sentence!!"}'
```

Of course, you can do step 2 in python script.

```
import requests


url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5005/model/parse'
myobj = {'text': 'Predict for this sentence!!'}

x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)

print(x.json())
```

You can extract just the intent by changing the last sentence in the python script.

```
print(x.json()['intent']['name'])
```

**Another way of getting Rasa NLU outputs only with Rasa core agent:**

```
import asyncio
from rasa.core.agent import Agent

class Model:

    def __init__(self, model_path: str) -> None:
        self.agent = Agent.load(model_path)
        print("NLU model loaded")


    def message(self, message: str) -> str:
        message = message.strip()
        return asyncio.run(self.agent.parse_message(message))

mdl = Model("models/x.tar.gz")
sentence = "Predict for this sentence!!"
print(mdl.message(sentence))
```

Again change the last line if you're only interested in the name of intent only.

```
print(mdl.message(sentence(['intent']['name'])))
```

The above code worked fine with Rasa 3.3.0.